# Python os path join ignores folder names

Tags: python-3.8

I am doing the following:

```
import os
ii = r'Z:\Monthly\iOT\2021'
dir0 = os.path.splitdrive(ii)[1]
dir1 = os.path.join(r'G:', r'My Drive', dir0)
```

`print(dir1)` gives `'G:\\Monthly\\iOT\\2021'` and completely ignores `'My Drive'`. I understand it has something to do with two backslashes in front of `dir0` but not sure how to remove it.

I was expecting

```
'G:\\My Drive\\Monthly\\iOT\\2021'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as following

```py
os.path.join('G:\\', r'My Drive', dir0[1:])
```

This "slices" the result of dir0, getting the characters from index 1 to the end of the string

This will result in

```
'G:\\My Drive\\Monthly\\iOT\\2021'
```

Remember the following, as stated in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

> On Windows, the drive letter is not reset when an absolute path component (e.g., r'\foo') is encountered. If a component contains a drive letter, all previous components are thrown away and the drive letter is reset. Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.